# Stop timeout within a function from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function One(){
   setTimeout(function(){ 
            Two();
    },3000);
}

function Two(){
   setTimeout(function(){ 
            One();
    },3000);
}

function Stop(){
   alert('this should run,and the functions above should stop');
}
```

I want to stop autorun of the first two functions,when you click on the third.
By now,if you click on the third,the alert shows up,but then the loop continue.Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

```
var oneTimeout, twoTimeout;

function One(){
   oneTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
            Two();
    },3000);
}

function Two(){
   twoTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
            One();
    },3000);
}

function Stop(){
   clearTimeout(oneTimeout);
   clearTimeout(twoTimeout);
   alert('this should run,and the functions above should stop');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you store the ID of the timeout call you can clear it at any time.

```
var timeoutId1, timeoutId2;

function One() {
  timeoutId1 = setTimeout(function() {
    Two();
  }, 3000);
}

function Two() {
  timeoutId2 = setTimeout(function() {
    One();
  }, 3000);
}

function Stop() {
  // alert('this should run,and the functions above should stop');
  clearTimeout(timeoutId1);
  clearTimeout(timeoutId2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
function TimerController(){
    var ids = {};
    this.start = function(id, time, fn) {
        if (ids[id]) clearTimeout(ids[id]);
        ids[id] = setTimeout(function(){
            fn();
            delete ids[id];
        }, time);
    }
    this.stop = function(id) {
        clearTimeout(ids[id]);
        delete ids[id];
    }
    this.stopAll = function() {
        for (var id in ids) this.stop(id);
    }
}

var ctrlr = new TimerController();

function One(){
    ctrlr.start('one', 3000, Two);
}

function Two(){
    ctrlr.start('two', 3000, One);
}
function Stop() {
    ctrlr.stopAll();
}
```

Little explanation:
timeouts and intervals in javascript both return identifier, that can be used for event cancelling.

```
var id = setTimeout(function(){console.log('Triggered!');}, 0); 
clearTimeout(id);
```

Function will never been called in the example above.

So, we should store timeout ids, if we want to be able to stop it.
`TimerController` above incapsulate this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `var timer = setTimeout(function()...); return timer;` in your first two function and pass the two `timer` variable (which holds a number identifying the timeout timer) to the third function. Then just call `clearTimeout(timer)` when the third function gets called.

Check out this [MDN docs for timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeout1;
//... Define Function name 
function rotate() {
timeout1 = setTimeout( rotate, 4000);
 }
```

- Another way

  ```
  var rotateTimeout;
  rotateTimeout = window.setInterval(rotate,4000); 
  window.clearInterval(rotateTimeout);
  ```